# Copy third party assemblies to sub folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I use various 3rd party assemblies in my project (native, nuget packages) that are sometimes optimized for different platforms (x86/amd64). Visual Studio automatically copies them in the application root (usually bin\Debug\PLATFORM), which creates a completely unstructorized mess.

Now I'm looking for a way to automatically copy 3rd party dlls into a custom subdirectory. I'm aware of various ways to LOAD assemblies from a different location than the application root (privatePath in app.config or in code), but not how to automatically copy them there.

**Desired structure**

```
bin\
    release\
        x64\
            MyApp.exe
            MyApp.exe.config
            cfg\
                custom.config
            lib\
                ninject\
                    Ninject.dll
                    Ninject.Extensions
                    Ninject.Extensions.Logging
                SomeNativeDll\
                    native_x64.dll
                OtherStuff.dll
        x86\
            ...
```

I've already found a way with Post Build Events, but declaring every reference with some batch like script language is a PITA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to add one extra project with your structure. The following steps recreate that:

1. Add a dll project:placeholder.csproj
2. Create the folder 'lib'
3. Create the subfolder 'ninject'
4. Add the file 'Ninject.dll' to that folder

   1. set the BuildAction to 'Content'
5. Add the placholder.csproj as a reference to yourt main project
6. Build

The *Content* files (but really being your dll's)  are now copied in the same folder structure in the output folder of your main project.

To support the platform specfic dll's it becomes a little trickier.

Unload the project and find your native file:

```
<Content Include="test\Some_X86.dll" >
 <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

and add a condition to it

```
<Content Include="test\Some_X86.dll" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'" >
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

if you only want to have the files for the x86 target in the output.